# How to make PyQt5 program starts like pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

As the title says i want to know how to make PyQt5 program starts like pycharm/spyder/photoshop/etc so when i open the program an image shows with progress bar(or without) like spyder,etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a splash screen. QSplashScreen will probably be your friend.